# Show element based on URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

1. I am working on one task where I need to hide an element and redirect it to another URL when user click on a div.
2. If user directly go to that URL then it should not hide element as it has not clicked yet.

I have manage to do FIRST point.

**Element will be on both pages**.

My logic is here but it is not working:

```
flag = false;

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("div.main").click(function() {
        flag==true;
        $(".notired").hide(); 
    });

    if ((document.location.href.indexOf("xyz") > 0) && (flag==true))
        $(".notired").hide();

});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <a href="xyz.com" title="Click here">
        <img src="../images/notif.png">
    </a>
    <span class="notired">';
        echo $count;
        echo '
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.notired
{
    display: inline-block;
    background: #E43C03;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    width: 14px;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-left:-9px;
}


.main
{
    width:50px;
}
```

Looking for the solution.

Comment: `flag==true;` doesn't set value. It should be `flag = true;` Also in `if` `flag` will always be equal to `false`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any other logic?

Comment: What do your URLs look like? Have you considered something like `:target { display : block; }`?

Comment: First of all you will have to figure out how to distinguish between “user got redirected to new URL via my script” and “user accessed that _exact same_ URL directly” – if the URL is _exactly_ the same, that is not possible of course by just looking at the URL itself, you will have to find an additional value to check against.

Comment: @KalpeshSingh you should provide your HTML code, because right now there are several unclear moments.

Comment: As Regent suggested,I have done that. Now,it is working partially but still when I directly jump on that URL it is hiding it. I have not considered that

Comment: Added HTML code. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidThomas. NO,I have not used that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your element is hidden by default, then:

- check if the current URL matches the one you need
- if it does, then do nothing as you want to keep it hidden
- if it doesn't then show it

and if i understood correctly you need always to hide on the click function, then simply put the `.hide()` inside the event handler

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    if(window.location.hash) {
        // The URL contains the hash sent when clicked on button
        $(".notired").hide();
    }
  });
```

and here

```
<a href="xyz.com#clicked" title="Click here">
```

Comment: I have change the URL here. I don't want to hide by default. 1. On page it should show. 2. if I click then it should hide and redirect to another page. 3. if I go to other URL directly then it should not hide it because it has not clicked yet.

Comment: so you only want to be working for these two pages only? then show it by default, and on click hide and only redirect if it passes the URL check

Comment: if i understood you correctly, you have a `<div>` that is shown by default. When you click on it, you want to hide it always but only if it is not on a specific page you want to hide and redirect. right ?

Comment: I have a div that will be on every page. It will show an element by default until it is clicked. If it is clicked then it will redirect to another page and would not show that element (because it is clicked on a page.) BUT if someone does not click and directly go to that specific URL then it should show because it has not clicked on any other pages.

Comment: @KalpeshSingh how do you go to another page? By completely refreshing page or by using ajax? If complete refresh is used, than you should use "localStorage" to save the fact that you've come to this page from this `div`.

Comment: well then what you need to capture is the URL sent. When a user clicks and is redirected to that page, you append a fragment to that URL via a # or whatever you wish. Then you check for that specific fragment, if it is found in the URL it means that the user reached to this page by clicking and not directly

Comment: @Regent exactly my thought, i suggested using URL fragments instead

Comment: Yes,it is refreshing page. Could you please elaborate localStorage? Is it complex thing?

Comment: @AhmadAssaf,I guess you are near to what I want. Please,send some links or example of this. Thanks!

Comment: <a href="xyz.com" title="Click here"> @AhmadAssaf

Comment: i thought you said a `<div>` ok i will update my answer

Comment: updated my answer, this way you will only get the hiding function when you know someone clicked on a button because only the # will appear when someone does :)

Comment: Thanks @AhmadAssaf . Let me check!

Comment: let me know, and if it works don't forget to mark the answer as solved please :)

Comment: +1 even though it will be a little more correct to compare `hash` with "clicked", not only hash's existance.

Comment: @AhmadAssaf How to manage this with session? Suppose user click on the element and logged off then again log in then element should not show until there is an update in element or '$count' is incremented or decremented.